# Search string substitute variable in a PowerShell command

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm attempting to prompt user input to search for specific emails using a piped command like this:

`get-mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | search-mailbox -searchquery 'subject:"*$Subject*"' -LogOnly -Loglevel Full -TargetMailbox "$Self" -TargetFolder "$Folder"}`

When I perform a search like this, the subject is never changed to what $Subject is even if I manually input it. I'm using a variable set like `$Subject = Read-Host "Type in the email subject"`

Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is have a technician choose what fields to search for an email with. Sender/Date/To/From etc. By choosing an option, it will perform the code in that section. The most important field is the Subject. But the subject never populates to what the variable is.
If I type the whole search string without variables it works perfectly.

What am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1#single-and-double-quoted-strings

Comment: I read that page earlier today but I'm not able to get it to work. The reason is that the Subject of the email is a text string and it must be surrounded by double quotes "string" to be valid. Otherwise powershell says it can't recognize the command. In addition, the entire search query must be encased in single quotes.  Example.. `search-query 'subject:"text string to search"'`.  The interesting thing, is the other variables populate fine. I do receive an email in the correct folder for the variables I input for $Self & $Folder

Comment: You can use double outer quotes and escape the inner double quotes with backticks: `"subject:\`"*$Subject*\`""`

Answer (score 0):

To expand the `$Subject` variable, construct the query first or inside parantheses:

```
$Subject="Good Morning"
$SearchQuery = 'Subject:'+'"*'+$subject+'*"'
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery $SearchQuery [...]
```

Comment: I got a little further. If I"m only searching for a subject and nothing else, I can omit the single quotes. `subject:$Subject` And it will go from there. The other thing I'm having issues with is using the AND operator to search for subject AND date. It's getting complex and the interpreter doesn't like that statement much without {}

Comment: @ShaunBrown yes, you'll have to add some logic to extend the search query string - I found if I didn't quote the subject value like `Subject:"blah blah"` then anything after a space gets treated as a separate search parameter - not limited to subject.